# Request to reopen the "part-time sysadmin" question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

[How to make sure a part time SysAdmin does not caught up in projects?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80491/how-to-make-sure-a-part-time-sysadmin-does-not-caught-up-in-projects/)

Querent has made significant edit, RTC too broad no longer applies

Answer (score 1):

Now re-opened. Your work here is done.